# Uncaught error:Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

[image: Error I'm getting in my browser console]When I trying to return the inserted image as json I'm getting error like **`Cannot use in operator to search for length`**

**`Ajax code:`**

```
 $("#imagesform").submit(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
  $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') 
  }
  });
  $.ajax({
      url      :"{{url('addImages/').'/'}}" + imagesProductId,
      type: 'POST',
      data:new FormData($("#imagesform").get(0)),
      contentType:false,
      processData:false,
      success: function (data)
       {
          //alert(data);
          //alert(json.parse(data));

       $.each(data, function( index, value ) {

      $("#insertedImages").append('<img src="'+value+'" width="75" 
      height="75" class="upload2"><br>');
          alert(value);

         });

      },

  });
  return false;
  });
```

Here the images get inserted into db.But while returning to the view and trying to display it with the div tag shows error..(specified above)

**Controller:**

```
public function addImages(Request $request,$imagesProductId)
{

$product = Product::create($request->all());
$filenames = array();

if (empty($request->images)) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
}


 $rules = [
 'images'=>'required'

];


      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
       $result    = $validator->fails() ? 'QCFailed' : 'QCVerified';
     // echo($result);


  foreach ($request->images  as $photo) {
   $filename = $photo->store('public/uploadedImages');
   $filename = substr($filename,22);
   $filenames[] = asset('storage/uploadedImages/'.$filename);
    ProductsPhoto::create([ 
        'product_id' => $product->id,
       'productId'=>$imagesProductId, 
       'nonliveStatus' => $result, 
        'filename' => $filename
    ]);
    }

    return response()->json($filename);

      }
```

This is my controller function for inserting array of images and I'm returning the same to the view and trying to append it using div tag.

Comment: is that a JavaScript error or a server error? Nowhere in your sample uses "in" directly, so presumably it's in one of the functions called from your code. Did you get a line number or function name, or anything, with your error? Usually you will. My guess is that's it's a JS error and that `data` is a string and not an object, therefore you can't iterate its properties. Try adding `dataType: "json"` as an option in the ajax call, which hints to jQuery that it should parse the response as JSON before passing it to the "success" callback.

Comment: Im not sure whether it isa javascript error or server error.

Comment: You can tell because of how it's reported. If you don't understand the difference, or how to spot the difference, you maybe need to study debugging at bit more. But I'm fairly sure (just from googling it, which you could also have done...) that it's a JS error, and that you should try my suggestion above.

Comment: Your edit just now confirms that it's a JS error. That's how they're shown in the Chrome console. And it references jquery etc in the stack trace which should give you a pretty big clue that it's a JS error, unless you have absolutely no idea about your code at all.

Comment: yes..I too added a `dataType:json` by googling with the error..but no changes

Comment: can't able to fix this issue..please help me in fixing this.

Comment: no, `dataType: "json"` with quote marks. Make sure you copy it exactly. If that doesn't work then please show a sample of what `data` looks like. We'll need to make sure it's actually a valid object.

Comment: Also, it looks like there is another error above the one you've shown in the screenshot. Was that the same thing, or a different one?

Comment: no,its a different one

Comment: well then we need to see that as well, obviously. All the errors are significant, not just one. I feel like you need to learn some basic debugging skills before you go much further.

Comment: ok..what should I need to do for that to fix my issue

Comment: anyone??/.........

Comment: okay erm basic things to do. 1. like ADyson said, all errors are significant. So check what is the error before this. 2. Is the image being saved in db? 3.If it is being saved, what is the type of data being returned from the controller. Need to provide more context in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Comment all those statements you've written in `success` function and add the statement `console.log(data);` to check out what is printed on the console window. Based on the response, you can decide what you need to do. Once the response looks like what you've expected, you can undo the comments and go ahead. Else you need to fix based on the issue you encountered. **Note**: If your response is a JSON string, you need to convert it to real JSON with `JSON.parse(data)` which you already have in the code and commented.

Comment: ok...ll try and update the changes

Comment: Okay. Sure mate. :)